# Jquery library not loading correctly

Tags: jquery

Im using the below code for Jquery datepicker but for some reason I get error while loading the jquery resources and inturn the datepicker is not displayed.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jquery-ui.min.js` is dependent on `jquery-1.11.1.js` so load first `jQuery` after that `jQuery-UI`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include your jQuery before jquery-ui.  Example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Also, on my localhost I had to include the http for the stylesheet.  Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is dependence among Jquery libraries. So ensure your order is correct.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I suggest to use Bower (software), a system for managing software packages to install all your libraries. It will take care all the dependency problems